# Hugo not ordering posts by modified date

Tags: go, go-templates, hugo

I want to order my front page by last modification, following the steps in [its documentation](https://gohugo.io/templates/lists/) it says this code

```
{{ range .Data.Pages.ByLastmod }}
```

Should work, but I am getting the posts ordered by date, not lastmod.

**Note**: Actually I am using paginator, so the code I am using is

```
{{ range .Paginator.Pages.ByLastmod }}
```

I've also tried the first snipped, but still ordering by date.

Anyone knows why?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First you must set the `lastmod` field in the front-matter. If you decide not set the field, then the lastmod date falls back to the `date` field in the front-matter.

If you wish to implement some automation, then you need to initialize your project as a Git repo, set flag `enableGitInfo = true` in the config file. You may find the details here: [gitinfo](https://gohugo.io/variables/git/#gitinfo-prerequisites)

Commit your repo changes before every build and you will see the `.Lastmod` date change accordingly.

Comment: I have lastmod param set in every post on my blog. So I guest that is not the problem.

Comment: I just tried what you said about `enableGitInfo` without success :-(

Comment: I hit the same issue, still no gain. Any change to achieve this?